# Libgdx couldnt load shared library gdx freetype for target linux 32bit, how do I fix?

Tags: java, android, linux, libgdx

I have started using libgdx and have been trying to get the freetypefont working on Android but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to get it working.  My app was working perfectly fine until I tried using freetypefont.  I have put the extensions in as directed on the libgdx web site.  The app crashes or stops working as soon as it starts.

The console says couldn't load shared library gdx-freetype for target linux 32-bit.  I feel like I have tried everything.  I have put the two freetype and freetype native files into the main game libs, I have put them into the desktop and only put the freetype one into the android lib.  I have used the latest nightly build .so files for the armeabi folders and still nothing.  I have also included the nightly build .so file for the x86 folder as suggested on here and still nothing.  If anyone has anything on this please help.  Thanks.

Comment: For me sounds like the library is compiled for 64 bits. Can you check this?

Comment: Sorry I can't confirm this there doesn't seem to be anything anywhere stating what it was compiled for. I got them from here http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/

Answer (score 7):

You have to add what is [listed here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle) for each project dependency in your *build.gradle* file.

> implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
>   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
>   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
>   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
>   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
>   natives
>   "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

Comment: Thanks it helped :)

Comment: I already voted this up a while ago, because it really helped. I put the actual list in your answer in case the source changes and because it's more convenient. I hope you don't mind! If you don't like it just rollback :)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a game using the same libraries running just fine. Here's the library information (using 'file') for the libraries that work:

```
libs/armeabi/libgdx-freetype.so:     ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
libs/armeabi-v7a/libgdx-freetype.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Check that you've got the proper libs and it should work just fine. FWIW, I'm running the nightlies (1.0-SNAPSHOT).

You might also want to check that you are running on ARM Android, since that is what those libraries are for. If you're running on x86 Android I am not sure that the freetype extension is supported.

Comment: Thanks sorry how did you find out the information for the libraries? when I open the .so files it shows a load of random characters.

Comment: Im running it on a Nexus 7 at the minute which I think is ARM.  But if I'm wanting this to run on a load of Android devices then surely it won't work.  How else could I display text?

Comment: Yes that is ARM, and yes, my game runs just fine on Nexus 7 with the same libraries as listed.

Comment: I decided to recreate a new project in libgdx and for some reason the font thing is working this time so I don't know what the problem was in the first place.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now its not working no more.  I am just going to give up with it it is depressing me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that for some reason `libgdx.so` was not copied to any of the `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` or `x86` folders in the android project's `lib` folder.

Copying these over from the libgdx distribution worked for me.

The setup-ui program simply copies things over from the libgdx distribution for you. You can find these folders there.