# Using Spatialite library on Libgdx android project give "Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit" error

Tags: android, libgdx, spatialite

I've developed an application using Libgdx game engine to show features from a shapefile layer. In order to get the geometry of features, I've used [Sevar83](https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite) a ported Spatilite database for Android which my shapefile inserted in it. The following is the build.gradle of my project that includes dependencies of Libgdx and Sevar83 libraries.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studio.testlibgdx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations { natives }
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.sevar83:android-spatialite:2.0.0'

    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.9.8"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.8"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.8:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.8:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.8:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.8:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.8:natives-x86_64"

    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.8"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.8:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.8:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.8:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.8:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.8:natives-x86_64"

}
```

The problem is running the application on Samsung J1 works find but on Samsung tab S2 it gives me this error. What makes this issue and how can I resolve it?

```
2019-06-21 11:28:57.022 29298-29298/com.studio.testlibgdx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.studio.testlibgdx, PID: 29298
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1500)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1390)
     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:125)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:33)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:63)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1500) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1390) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.studio.testlibgdx-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libgdx.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:119)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:33) 
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:63) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1500) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1390)
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28387088/6250401

Comment: @LuisFernandoFrontanilla sorry, but I've added those before. Just missed when pasting in the question form.